# FFmpeg losslessly deconstruct video then losslessly re-encode

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, lossless, h.265

I need to dump all the frames losslessly from a h.265 mkv video, along with the audio track in FLAC 24bit (initially it was encoded from the source in FLAC 24bit). I then need to edit some frames and encode these frames with the audio track back to h.265 with mkv as the container, all of this process must be lossless.

If it's possible, I'd like to compress losslessly where I can. Is all of this possible to do in FFmpeg?

I've searched the FFmpeg documentation but it seems to lack a lot of information on the options used for lossless video editing/encoding. If you could point me in the right direction that would be a big help.

Comment: Do you wish to edit the frames inside or outside of ffmpeg?

Comment: You understand the the resulting file will be much large that the original correct?